# There seems to be a problem with meta.SFF.SE posts not feeding into SFF chat

Tags: support, chat, feed

This was reported by @Slytherincess on chat, and I don't think I recall recent meta posts appearing either.

Regular SFF questions appear, but with sometimes long delay,

Comment: It'd be a height of irony if this post shows up in chat after a couple of minutes

Comment: [It did](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=7110693#7110693) :) But that was actually me checking if everything is okay. [Recent Meta posts are there](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/-25/sff-meta?tab=recent), but you're right about the delay. We may have to increase some numbers, since chat.stackexchange has a fairly high amount of feeds these days, while the numbers haven't changed in two years. I'll look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It look like they are Feeding fine :

http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7110693#7110693

[image: screen cap]